# Why are effect size estimates (such as $R^2$) difficult in mixed-effects models?

Tags: mixed-model, effect-size

I have been reading a lot online about estimating standardised effect sizes in mixed effects models and it seems like there are formidable challenges even for something relatively broad like an $R^2$, let alone for contrasts. What is a simple explanation (that I could supply to a reviewer) for why effects sizes are so challenging to perform in these more complex models?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing inherently challenging. What is challenging is getting a consensus on how many degrees of freedom a LMEM has and what an $R^2$ is supposed to reflect in a LMEM. As soon as two parties agree on these matters, the coefficients of determination and effect sizes are "trivial" to calculate. That's why we have all those metrics like $\Omega^2$ (Xu, 2003), pseudo-$R^2$ (Hössjer, 2008, or Nakagawa & Schielzeth, 2013) and approximations like Satterthwaite's (Satterthwaite, 1946), Kenward-Roger's (Kenward & Roger 1997), etc. The Journal of Statistical Software article on [`lmerTest`](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v082i13/v82i13) offers an excellent discussion on the matter. To that extent, Douglas Bates, the linear mixed effects models' [OG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_gangster), has expressed some of his thoughts on the matter of [R2 measure in mixed models](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q1/003363.html) online. I fully agree.

Comment: Thank you @user11852. What about standardised effect sizes for custom contrasts within mixed-effects models? They seem to be much harder to obtain than for single-level models?

Comment: Also, loved 'OG'.

Comment: Cool! Regarding your comment's question: In general, custom (or Helmert) contrasts are context-specific analysis constructs and we need to carefully assess how many degrees of freedom they dictate. Nevertheless, the custom nature of the contrast is not the main issue; as before it is the inclusion of the random effects that complicates our problem's definition.

Comment: Yes I figured the random effects were the problem. I am mounting an argument to the reviewer than the unstandardised regression coefficients are a better indicator of the *size* (rather than the *noticeability*) of the effects in question than a standardised effect size. Thanks for the references!